# Postgres default privileges do not seem to work

Tags: postgresql, role

I am trying to set up RBAC in Postgres where I have a database and a schema. I have a few roles `provisioner`, `service`, `mydb_ro`, and `mydb_rw`. I ran the following to change default privileges

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE provisioner IN SCHEMA mydb_schema
    GRANT SELECT                           ON TABLES TO mydb_ro;  -- only read

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE provisioner IN SCHEMA mydb_schema
    GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE ON TABLES TO mydb_rw;  -- + write, TRUNCATE optional

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE provisioner IN SCHEMA mydb_schema
    GRANT REFERENCES, TRIGGER              ON TABLES TO mydb_rw;  -- + TRIGGER

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE provisioner IN SCHEMA mydb_schema
    GRANT USAGE, SELECT, UPDATE            ON SEQUENCES TO mydb_rw;  -- SELECT, UPDATE are optional

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE provisioner IN SCHEMA mydb_schema
    GRANT EXECUTE                          ON FUNCTIONS TO mydb_rw;
```

this is what I see in default privileges

```
postgres@mydb=> \ddp
                           Default access privileges
┌─────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│    Owner    │      Schema      │   Type   │        Access privileges        │
├─────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ provisioner │ mydb_schema      │ function │ mydb_rw=X/provisioner           │
│ provisioner │ mydb_schema      │ sequence │ mydb_rw=rwU/provisioner         │
│ provisioner │ mydb_schema      │ table    │ mydb_ro=r/provisioner          ↵│
│             │                  │          │ mydb_rw=awdDxt/provisioner      │
└─────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
```

But when I am logged in as a user that has the `provisioner` role and I create a table, a user that has `service` role cannot see it. What am I doing wrong?

I now ran

```
GRANT mydb_ro TO mydb_rw;
GRANT mydb_rw TO service;
```

But that did not help with the permission issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the 'provisioner' role is not the same thing as being 'provisioner'.

For your shown default permission to apply, you would have to create the object as 'provisioner' (for example, `SET ROLE provisioner;` before you create the objects)